# How *not* to return the relationships that link a node to itself in neo4J

Tags: neo4j

In the database that I am using, nodes often have multiple relationships to *themselves* which makes the resulting graph very messy. As this is for a presentation how do we structure a Cypher query which does *not* return the self-referencing **relationships**

I have tried

```
match p=((n:actor) -[*1..3]-> (nd:movie)) where n.name='Craig' and nd.name='Pride_and_prejudice' and not (n)-[]->(n) return p
```

didnt give the desired result.

Comment: What result *did* your query give you?

Comment: try `match p=((n:actor) -[r:*1..3]-> (nd:movie)) where n.name='Craig' and nd.name='Pride_and_prejudice' and not (n)-[r]->(n) return p`

Comment: @MartinPreusse I simply get the same result as the query without the *not* statement

Comment: @Supamiu I get an error when I try that: Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of relationships from `Actor` to itself, the variable length path query might not be ideal. It will always include the self-referencing relationships which limits performance and gives too many results. One solution would be to explicitly `MATCH` the first step and filter for the label:

```
MATCH p=( (n:actor)-[r1]-(n1)-[*0..2]->(nd:Movie) ) 
WHERE NOT n1:actor
RETURN ...
```

The `*0..2` relationship will catch cases where `n1` is a `Movie`.

Alternatively, you can filter the variable length path for a property as described here: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-match.html#match-match-with-properties-on-a-variable-length-path

Comment: I am running this now, and the run time is very slow. I executed the query about 10 minutes ago. The original query took about a second, not sure why this is..? So have not been able to check if this gives the correct answer

Comment: unfortunatley, it did not work, self referencing actors still appear in the results

Comment: basically some of the intermediary nodes are of type *director* and these have self referencing relationships.

Comment: If you start with `Actor` and the next node is `NOT Actor`, you should not get `Actor-Actor` relationships. In general: If everything is self referencing and you need unfiltered variable length queries, you should rethink your graph model.